# Accessing previous props in getDerivedStateFromProps method

Tags: reactjs

I have an application which is created with `React 16.3.X` and needs `this.props` in `getDerivedStateFromProps()` method.

for example:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  console.log(this.props);  // `this` is not defined
  if (nextProps.id !== this.props.id) {
    // do something...
  }
  return null;
}
```

Obviously `this` is not defined in a `static` method, but I need to know is there any way to get `this.props` in `getDerivedStateFromProps()`?

Comment: Why do you want to access `this.props` inside `getDerivedStateFromProps`?

Comment: I need to compare with nextProps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot access `this.props` inside `getDerivedStateFromProps` function. If you want to access some previous props (like for comparison) inside the function, then you can mirror such values inside the `state`. Then you can compare the `nextProps` with the value stored in `state` like this

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (nextProps.id !== prevState.id) {
    // prevState.id represent the prevProps.id
    return {id: nextProps.id};
  }
  return null;
}
```

Checkout: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#updating-state-based-on-props

Answer (score 0):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is superset for `componentWillReceiveProps` you can't get `this.props` inside it. If you need it you did something wrong as it is anti-pattern. If you need it you can still use deprecated method https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops which is ofcourse not advised as it will be removed. Please post the code why you need it as clearly you are introducing anti pattern.

Comment: I've added my compare example

Answer (score 0):

you could store the current props inside the state. similar to this:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    prevProps: []
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    let stateToBeReturned = null;
    if (prevState.prevProps !== nextProps.data) {
      stateToBeReturned =  {
        ...prevState,
        prevProps: nextProps.data,
      }
    }
    return stateToBeReturned;
  }
}
```